# Data is not coming in recycler view items

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-json

I am using volley library for JSON parsing in the `RecyclerView` to fetch the data from server  but `ProgressBar` keeps on running and no data is coming

My php script is fine as I check it is getting updated when I send data from other activity

```
public class LiveFeeds extends AppCompatActivity {

List<DataAdapter> DataAdapterClassList;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

ProgressBar progressBar;

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

ArrayList<String> SubjectNames;

RequestQueue requestQueue ;

String HTTP_SERVER_URL = "http://ledeveloper.in/bit/getbiddata.php";

View ChildView ;

int RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_feeds);

    DataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

    SubjectNames = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    // JSON data web call function call from here.
    JSON_WEB_CALL();

    //RecyclerView Item click listener code starts from here.
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(LiveFeeds.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                return true;
            }

        });
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            ChildView = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if(ChildView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                //Getting RecyclerView Clicked item value.
                RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);

                //Printing RecyclerView Clicked item clicked value using Toast Message.
              //  Toast.makeText(LiveFeeds.this, SubjectNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });

}

public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_SERVER_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setId(json.getInt("id"));

            GetDataAdapter2.setName(json.getString("username"));

            //Adding subject name here to show on click event.
          //  SubjectNames.add(json.getString("name"));

            GetDataAdapter2.setPrice(json.getString("price"));

            GetDataAdapter2.setQuantity(json.getString("quan"));
            GetDataAdapter2.setTotal(json.getString("total"));
            GetDataAdapter2.setTime(json.getString("bidtime"));
            GetDataAdapter2.setDate(json.getString("bidbdate"));


        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}
```

}

This is my Adapter class
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;

List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();

    this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    DataAdapter dataAdapter =  dataAdapters.get(position);

    viewHolder.ID.setText(dataAdapter.getId());

    viewHolder.USERNAME.setText(String.valueOf(dataAdapter.getName()));

    viewHolder.PRICE.setText(dataAdapter.getPrice());

    viewHolder.QUANTITY.setText(dataAdapter.getQuantity());

    viewHolder.TOTAL.setText(dataAdapter.getTotal());

    viewHolder.TIME.setText(dataAdapter.getTime());

    viewHolder.DATE.setText(dataAdapter.getDate());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataAdapters.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

   public TextView ID,USERNAME,PRICE,QUANTITY,TOTAL,TIME,DATE;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        ID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2) ;
        USERNAME = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showusername) ;
        PRICE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showprice) ;
        QUANTITY = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showquantt) ;
        TOTAL = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showtotal) ;
        TIME = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showtime) ;
        DATE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showdate) ;


    }
}
```

}

This is my data binding class

```
public class DataAdapter {

int Id;
String username;
String price;
String quantity;
String total;
String time;
String date;



public String getName() {

    return username;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.username = name;
}

public int getId() {

    return Id;
}

public void setId(int Id1) {

    this.Id = Id1;
}


public String getPrice() {

    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String pprice) {

    this.price = pprice;
}

public String getQuantity() {

    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quant) {

    this.quantity = quant;
}

public String getTotal() {

    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String tot) {

    this.total = tot;
}

public String getTime() {

    return time;
}

public void setTime(String timm) {

    this.time = timm;
}

public String getDate() {

    return date;
}

public void setDate(String datt) {

    this.date = datt;
}
```

}

This is my php script

```
$respone = array();

if(isset($_GET['username'])){
$username = $_GET['username'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM bidtable ORDER BY id DESC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)

{
   while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $product = array();

    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["username"] = $row["username"];
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
$product["quan"] = $row["quan"];
$product["total"] = $row["total"];
$product["bidtime"] = $row["bidtime"];


    $response["success"] = "true";
    $response["product"] = array();
    array_push($response["product"], $product);
    echo json_encode($response);

}
}



else{
    $response["success"] = "false";
    $response["message"] = "Something went wrong";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}
else{
$response["success"] = "false";
$response["message"] = "Required data not set.";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: When you debug it, doe sit reach this line recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter)?

Comment: No It is not reaching

Comment: So I'd suggest you first try to debut that. See where it is failing. Also check.the logcat window for errors

Answer (score 0):

You don't have passed username parameter in the request. Pass username parameter in URL like this:

```
http://ledeveloper.in/bit/getbiddata.php?username=<username>
```

Ex : http://ledeveloper.in/bit/getbiddata.php?username=gaurav

Also, add this line in onErrorResponse

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Data is not coming in recycler view

Comment: I am getting this response on calling API {"success":"false","message":"Required data not set."}

Comment: I have added my php script @kunwar97